# How to display selected contact of WhatsApp in my application

Tags: android, whatsapp

I am able to Launch whatsApp and send text from my application.

Problem is i want to save the selected whatsApp contact(onActivityResult) in my application and want to send when the user wish.
I don't want to launch every time to send text to same contact.

I have searched many post, i found only launch and sending text after launch. Is there any way to read and save the contact similar to phone contact.

Is it not supported by WhatsApp to save.Hope you can help..

Comment: Isn't that not just blocked for obvious security reasons. Whatsapp needs to ask permission for accessing ones contacts in his address book, but an app without that authorization could just access Whatsapp to act as intermediary to siphon the contact data from the phone. Not saying that this is the purpose of your app.

Comment: Sorry i din't get clear picture. You mean we need permission to query and save particular contact address and it is not allowed from whatsApp for other application. am i correct

Comment: That is my educated guess. Whenever some developer installs an app on my phone I need to give it permission to access my microphone, contacts, etc. Whatsapp isn't going to expose that data to third party apps.